# How to Geo-tag an image using latitude and longitude from a text file?

Tags: python, image, gps, exiftool

I have an image captured using a camera attached to a drone. The camera I used does not give me any GPS data, however my drone has an in-built GPS which I can use to get the location at which the image was captured. I save this information in a text file. How do I add this latitude and longitude saved in the text file to the image? I am writing my code in python. So far I have only found information about using csv or gpx files with exiftool but nothing about text files.

Answer (score 3):

```py
import exiftool

et = exiftool.ExifTool("C:\Users\...\exiftool.exe")
et.execute("-GPSLongitude=10.0", "picture.jpg")
et.execute("-GPSLatitude=5.78", "picture.jpg")
et.execute("-GPSAltitude=100", "picture.jpg")
et.terminate()
```

And without terminate() statement

```py
with exiftool.ExifTool("C:\Users\...\exiftool.exe") as et:
    et.execute("-GPSLongitude=10.0", "picture.jpg")
    et.execute("-GPSLatitude=5.78", "picture.jpg")
    et.execute("-GPSAltitude=100", "picture.jpg")
```

Also as the user @StarGeek said

> You also have to set the GPSLatitudeRef and GPSLongitudeRef values,
>   especially if the value is in the western or southern hemisphere. It
>   can be done the same way et.execute("-GPSLongitudeRef=10.0",
>   "picture.jpg") – StarGeek

Comment: You also have to set the `GPSLatitudeRef` and `GPSLongitudeRef` values, especially if the value is in the western or southern hemisphere.  It can be done the same way `et.execute("-GPSLongitudeRef=10.0", "picture.jpg")`